# Можно ли как-то упростить код в koa-body?

Tags: node.js, koa.js

Использую модуль koa-body более упрощенного способа так не нашел, даже сохранение путь в бд, он как-то громоздко получился
Я подключаю в модуля я указываю все параметры

```js
bodyParser = require('koa-body'),
app.use(bodyParser({
    formidable:{
        uploadDir: path.join(__dirname + '/public/upload/'),
        keepExtensions: true},
    multipart: true,
    urlencoded: true
}));
```

в Роуте

```js
router.post('/create-order', async ctx => {
        let pathUpload = ctx.request.body.files.image.path;
        let parse = pathUpload.split('\\');
        ctx.request.body.fields.file = `${parse[4]}/${parse[5]}/${parse[6]}`;
        try {
            let order = new Order(ctx.request.body);
            ctx.body = await true;
        } catch (err) {
            ctx.body = await err
        }
    });
```